# Storing file input into dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have written small program in Python which reads the following file and stores the result into a dictionary. I am getting expected output but I think it can be done in a better way. I am using Python 3.

Input

```
check_name : xa25
not run:
del_l6w_
dl_l4w_
dl_l22w_
de_l3w_
ckt_pw_
ckt_pw_
run:
inv_w_
buf_w_
End
```

Code

```
import collections
def main():
    chk_cell = "input.txt"
    chk_cell_data = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    with open(chk_cell, "r") as fchk_cell:
        check_name = ""
        not_run_flag = False
        run_flag = False
        for data in fchk_cell.readlines():
            data = data.strip()
            if not data:
                continue
            if data.startswith('check_name'):
                data = data.split(":")
                check_name = data[1].strip()
                continue
            elif data.startswith('End') or '-' in data:
                check_name = ""
                not_run_flag = False
                run_flag = False
                continue
            elif data.startswith('not run'):
                chk_cell_data[check_name]['not_run'] = []
                not_run_flag = True
                continue
            elif data.startswith('run'):
                chk_cell_data[check_name]['run'] = []
                not_run_flag = False
                run_flag = True
                continue
            
            if not_run_flag:
                chk_cell_data[check_name]['not_run'].append(data)
            
            elif run_flag:
                chk_cell_data[check_name]['run'].append(data)
    print(chk_cell_data)
           
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Type strength

Unless you have a really (really) good reason to use a `dict` - such as planning to immediately serialize to JSON for some network operation - `dict` is a poor choice for an internal representation. Use a `@dataclass`.

### Parsing strictness

You should be a little more strict about your parsing; your current implementation considers

```
check_name_for_something_that_makes_no_sense
```

to be a `check_name` heading, and a data entry under the `run:` heading called

```
check_name
```

to be a heading instead of a data entry. Instead, just compare the whole line.

Your example data do not show any reason for your `-` check to be there, so I see no reason for it to exist.

### Parse state

Instead of hanging onto flags to remember parse state, you can simply assign a reference to the list currently being populated.

### Explicit iteration

No need to call `readlines`. Just iterate over the file object itself.

### Example implementation

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TextIO, List


@dataclass
class RunData:
    name: str
    run: List[str]
    not_run: List[str]

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, f: TextIO) -> 'RunData':
        run = []
        not_run = []
        current_list = None
        name = None

        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if line == 'run:':
                current_list = run
            elif line == 'not run:':
                current_list = not_run
            elif line.startswith('check_name :'):
                name = line.split(': ', 1)[1]
            elif line == 'End':
                return cls(name, run, not_run)
            else:
                current_list.append(line)


def main():
    chk_cell = "input.txt"
    with open(chk_cell, "r") as fchk_cell:
        chk_cell_data = RunData.from_file(fchk_cell)
    print(chk_cell_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

prints

```
RunData(name='xa25', run=['inv_w_', 'buf_w_'], not_run=['del_l6w_', 'dl_l4w_', 'dl_l22w_', 'de_l3w_', 'ckt_pw_', 'ckt_pw_'])
```